# HTML code being displayed instead of resulting output from a column in List

Tags: list, 2013, xslt, rich-text

I have a column named "Detail" in my list and its type is "Rich Text". When I insert some item in this list for e.g. "This is a test" and when I display this list on home page of my site using XSLT then it is displayed as:

```
<div class="ExternalClass5DKHDKFHJKJDKG"><This is a test</div>
```

So basically it is displaying actual HTML code instead of resulting output. The code I am using in XSLT is as follows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Detail"/>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 'disable-output-escaping="yes"' in your xslt

Example:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Detail" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

This will fix your problem.